# TypeError although same shape: if not (target.size() == input.size()): 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, pytorch

This is the error message I get. In the first line, I output the shapes of `predicted` and  `target`. From my understanding, the error arises from those shapes not being the same but here they clearly are.

```
torch.Size([6890, 3]) torch.Size([6890, 3])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 251, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 230, in main
    train(net, training_dataset, targets, device, criterion, optimizer, epoch, args.epochs)
  File "train.py", line 101, in train
    loss = criterion(predicted, target.detach().cpu().numpy())
  File "/home/hb119056/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 493, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hb119056/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 443, in forward
    return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)
  File "/home/hb119056/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2244, in mse_loss
    if not (target.size() == input.size()):
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I hope all the relevant context information is provided and if not, please let me know. Thanks for any suggestions!

EDIT: This is the part of the code where this error occurs:

```
        target = torch.from_numpy(np.load(file_dir + '/points/points{:03}.npy'.format(i))).to(device)
        rv = torch.zeros(12 * outputs.shape[0])

        for j in [x for x in range(10) if x != i]:
            source = torch.from_numpy(np.load(file_dir + '/points/points{:03}.npy'.format(j))).to(device)
            rv = factor.ransac(source, target, prob, n_iter, tol, device) # some self-written RANSAC-like method

        predicted = factor.predict(source, rv, outputs)
        print(target.shape, predicted.shape)
        loss = criterion(predicted, target.detach().cpu().numpy()) ## error occurs here
```

`criterion` is `nn.MSELoss()`.

Comment: Looks like `size` is not a method but just an attribute. Try `if target.size != input.size:`. Although it's certainly weird that this problem seems to be in a library. Maybe you are using incompatible dependency versions?

Comment: @tobias_k `target.size` is indeed not equal to `input.size`. I don't know about the dependencies though.

Answer (score 4):

A little bit late but maybe it will help someone else. Just solved the same problem for myself.

As Alpha said in his answer we cannot call `.size()` for a numpy array.
But we can call `.size()` for a tensor.
Therefore, we need to make our target a tensor. You can do it like this:

```
target = torch.from_numpy(target)
```

I'm using GPU, so I also needed to send my target to GPU. You can do it like this:

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
target = target.to(device)
```

And then the loss function must work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It probably means that you are trying to call a method when a property with the same name is available. If this is indeed the problem, the solution is easy. Simply change the method call into a property access.

If you are comparing in the following way:

```
compare = (X.method() == Y.method())
```

Change it to:

```
compare = (X.method == Y.method)
```

If this does not answer your question, kindly share the code which you have used to compare the shapes.

Comment: Thank you but I don't see that this is what's happening in my code. So I'm just gonna append that snippet of the code.

Comment: Could you make sure that both the predicted and target variable are numpy arrays? While computing predicted, just use np.asarray(). If that does not work, try reshaping both the arrays to the same shape.

Comment: `predicted` can't be a numpy array because I have to backpropagate its gradient.

Comment: Then reshape both predicted and target to the shape which you expect them to be.

Comment: Try it once please! `loss = criterion(predicted.reshape(6890,3), target.detach().cpu().numpy().reshape(6890,3))`

Comment: Okay, I tried it and it's still the same error as in the beginning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198722/discussion-between-miracle-and-rani).

Answer (score 1):

that's because your `target` is a `numpy` object

```
File "train.py", line 101, in train:
target.detach().cpu().numpy()
```

in your code change the `target` type to numpy.

TLDR  try change

```
loss = criterion(predicted, target.detach().cpu().numpy()) ## error occurs here
```

to

```
loss = criterion(predicted, target) ## error occurs here
```

---

for example:

```
In [6]: b = np.ones(3)                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [7]: b.size                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[7]: 3

In [8]: b.size()                                                                                                                                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-365705555409> in <module>
----> 1 b.size()

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: I had to convert `target` to a numpy array because otherwise I would get another error that states that it should be a numpy array.

Comment: if you want to compute loss and back propagate the loss, you can't change to `numpy`. There maybe be another error.

Comment: you could use `loss = criterion(predicted, target)` and then ask your new question.

Comment: Oh okay, so do both the predicted and target model have to be torch tensors?

Comment: yes.  `tensor` type can store the gradient used for back propagation.  Consider give me a useful response:)

Comment: You're right, the error probably lies somewhere else. I created [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57725608/pytorch-runtimeerror-function-mulbackward0-returned-an-invalid-gradient-at-ind), maybe you wanna take a look? :)