# PyTorch: RuntimeError: Function MulBackward0 returned an invalid gradient at index 0 - expected type torch.cuda.FloatTensor but got torch.FloatTensor

Tags: python, pytorch, backpropagation

I don't understand what this error is telling me. In [a different post](https://github.com/NVIDIA/flownet2-pytorch/issues/139) the same problem was also addressed but there was no useful solution for this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 252, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 231, in main
    train(net, training_dataset, targets, device, criterion, optimizer, epoch, args.epochs)
  File "train.py", line 103, in train
    loss.backward()
  File "/home/hb119056/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 107, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
  File "/home/hb119056/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 93, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: Function MulBackward0 returned an invalid gradient at index 0 - expected type torch.cuda.FloatTensor but got torch.FloatTensor
```

This is the corresponding segment from my code.

```
outputs = net(x, indices)
outputs = outputs.transpose(0, 1)
prob = F.normalize(outputs, p=1, dim=1).detach()
target = torch.from_numpy(np.load(file_dir + '/points/points{:03}.npy'.format(i))).to(device)
rv = torch.zeros(12 * outputs.shape[0])

for j in [x for x in range(10) if x != i]:
    source = torch.from_numpy(np.load(file_dir + '/points/points{:03}.npy'.format(j))).to(device)
    rv = factor.ransac(source, target, prob, n_iter, tol, device) # self-written

predicted = factor.predict(source, rv, outputs, device) # self-written
loss = criterion(predicted, target.type(torch.FloatTensor).to(device))
loss.backward() # error occurs here
optimizer.step()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: does my answer work? if not, you can tell me what's the error with my answer.

Comment: have you tried the suggestion from here https://github.com/NVIDIA/flownet2-pytorch/issues/146 also?

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
loss = criterion(predicted, target.type(torch.FloatTensor).to(device))
```

to

```
predicted = predicted.to(device)
target=target.type(predicted.type()).to(predicted.device)
loss = criterion(predicted, target)
```

Comment: This is the error `TypeError: dtype must be a type, str, or dtype object` for the first line of your answer.

Comment: I tried it again an now the error is again the same as in the beginning.

Comment: Emm. I update again.    BTW, I'm not sure what's your `predicted` and `target` type. and what's the `device` value.

Comment: After modifying target, both devices are cuda:0 and the types are `torch.cuda.FloatTensor`.

Answer (score 0):

try changing 
`loss = criterion(predicted, target.type(torch.FloatTensor).to(device))`
to
`loss = criterion(predicted, target.to(device).float())`

Comment: are you not calling `zero_grad` on purpose btw? not sure if this is related. Anyways maybe try printing the device of predicted and target (after moving it) with type

Comment: I'm calling `zero_grad` right before the code snippet begins. Hm after moving both devices are cuda:0 and the types are `torch.cuda.FloatTensor`.

Comment: Ok maybe this is a very specific issue you are facing

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar problem. The error mainly comes from the loss failing to converge and getting bigger and bigger.

You can find this explanation in the Pytorch forum: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-function-mulbackward0-returned-nan-values-in-its-0th-output/70346/19.